# How to prove Drinker paradox using Resolution?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There exists a famous [Drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox): $\exists x[P(x)\implies \forall yP(y)]$

How to prove it using resolution?

Here is my attempt:

1. Negated and Skolemized: $\forall x$ $P(x) \wedge \neg P(f(x))$
2. Clausal Form: {P(x)}, {~P(f(x))}
3. Stuck at this step. I do not understand how to unify these terms to do resolution and produce an empty clause.

Comment: The Drinker paradox (as you have it) is a kind of cautionary tale when applying existential generalizations to an implication. You can get some very strange results. Usually, you would apply it to a conjunction. See https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/the-drinkers-paradox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $x$ is universally quantified, you can substitute any term for $x$.

In particular, from $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(f(x))$, you can get $P(f(x))$ and $\lnot P(f(x))$, which are contradictory (i.e., resolve to the empty clause).